# how to install .deb app packages using gnome-software

Tags: gnome, software-installation, mate

I'm using ubuntu mate 22.04 and after installing gnome-software the sources only show flatpaks and snaps, while I am able to install .deb using synaptics & apt, I'd like to use gnome software for installing and updating all my apps.

Did something changed over the years? I'm using ubuntu after 2 years.

Comment: The standard "Ubuntu Software" app that comes with 22.04 by default does exactly what you want. For updates (apt and snap) you can use the apply named "Updates" tool if you want a GUI (for apt and snap). I see no point in using `gnome-software` really. Anyway you should be able to open the debs with it if you want.

Comment: open a console and use dpkg -i package.deb

Comment: New releases come out each April & October; after 20.04 a new *development* cycle started with 20.10, 21.04, 21.10 and it completes with the LTS or 22.04.  Ubuntu 20.04 was the prior LTS and it's *development* cycle started with 18.10. There is always change; esp. if comparing a LTS from a prior cycle to the next LTS or the product of a subsequent development cycle.  GNOME Software however does exactly as you want.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you but both ubuntu software and Updates tool are not available in my ubuntu mate repos, I've synaptics,software boutique and gnome software only. If possible please share the packages with me.

Comment: @guiverc I only've flatpaks and snaps in gnome software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by uninstalling firefox snap and refreshing my repos.